# How do I use cloudinary with ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs-flux, cloudinary

I'm currently building an app using reactjs on the flux architecture.

I’m trying to use `cloudinary` for node (npm installed) to handle image uploads but when I try to call the uploader function, I get an error `post_request.setTimeout() is not a function` .

I’ve been stuck on an issue for sometime now and would appreciate any pointers. Thanks in advance.

What I did

1. `npm install cloudinary`
2. `import cloudinary from 'cloudinary'`
3. `cloudinary.config(params)`
4. `cloudinary.uploader.upload( image_url, callback)`

From the docs, I should be able to call `cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, callback, options)` where file is either the file name or the image url

The logs give the error `post_request.setTimeout() is not a function`

I'd appreciate any tip that could help with this upload. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve this yet?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to perform server-side uploading, with the Node.js library, you can have a look at the [sample projects](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/tree/master/samples).
If you'd like to perform client-side uploads then while Cloudinary currently don't offer an SDK for React, one of the following options may help:

1. You can look at either of our [jQuery](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js) or [Angular](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular) open source SDKs to have a look at their implementations.
2. You can use our [Upload widget](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) to upload images from the client-side with very little coding to do.
3. If the images are uploaded from remote URLs and not user's local files, you can use our remote images fetching features -http://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images.

Comment: There is an javasciprt only SDK now, but I can't find it's documentation... How can I use it instead of bundling my application with jQuery? (I am supposing you work at Cloudinary because of "our remote images" above)

Comment: Sorry for my response delay, missed it for some reason. Yes, I do work at Cloudinary :). Here's the full pure Javascript documentation - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/javascript_integration. Uploading without jQuery can be done either by Pure Javascript (here's a basic sample -
 https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK), or by using the Upload Widget (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget)

Comment: **UPDATE**:

In January 2018 Cloudinary released the React SDK.
Here's the documentation page:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration

and here's the repo in GitHub:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react. 

Feel free to also test out the sample project there.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not so focused on attending React developers at this time, with the upload functionality.

We are using here [React Cloudinary Uploader](https://github.com/app-masters/react-cloudinary-uploader) for Rect, and it's has been the best approach right now.

You can use the full visual component, that will show an upload button, the image uploaded and handle the crop, like this:

```
<ReactCloudinaryUploader
    cloudName='appmasters-io'
    uploadPreset='willim-dev'
    onUploadSuccess={(image)=>{
        console.log("image",image);
    }}
/>
```

Or, you can call all statically and implement your view like you want, like this:

```
let options = {
    cloud_name: "demo",
    upload_preset: "a5vxnzbp",
    multiple: true,
    returnJustUrl: true
};

ReactCloudinaryUploader.open(options).then(image=>{
    if (this.props.returnJustUrl)
        image = image.url;
    console.log("image",image);
}).catch(err=>{
    console.error(err);
});
```

I think it could be better than using the old javascript style mixed with React.

Comment: Are you sure about that, what about https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react